# How to handle Angularjs routing in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

This is my Project structure:-

[image]

The following is my ngRoute code:-

```
mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    //Homepage
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'directoryController'
})
.when('/edit', {
    //Edit Templates
    templateUrl: 'details.html',
    controller: 'tempUnguidedEditController'
  })

});
```

This is my Spring controller class :-

```
    @Controller
    public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView home() {
      return new ModelAndView("index");
   }



   @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard.html")
   public ModelAndView dashboard() {
      return new ModelAndView("dashboard");
    }


}
```

When I run the dashboard.html link it gives an error on console log:-

[image]

When I run the my web pages separately on browser it works but when I integrate it with Spring it fails to locate some files. I guess I am doing something wrong in the project structure which is why it is not able to find `main.html` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by,

i) Converting main.html,guided.html and unguided.html to main.jsp,guided.jsp and unguided.jsp.

ii) Then i intercepted the requests for all of the three individual routes in my `MainController` class.

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/home.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView home() {
      return new ModelAndView("index");
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard.html")
   public ModelAndView dashboard() {
      return new ModelAndView("dashboard");
    }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/main.html")
   public ModelAndView main() {
      return new ModelAndView("main");
    }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/guided.html")
   public ModelAndView guided() {
      return new ModelAndView("guided");
    }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/unguided.html")
   public ModelAndView unguided() {
      return new ModelAndView("unguided");
    }


}
```

Comment: didn't understand. I am facing same problem.Please share detail solution.

Comment: If I maintain  my view pages under WEB-INF then it doesn't work but if I pull them under webcontent then it works. Where and what to configure if I want to maintain my view under WEB-INF